# AWS API: how to cast dynamo result as class

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have a model repository that utilizes the C# AWS SDK for Dynamo. Right now it's a bit ugly. What I'd like is to cast-out result items to my model. Going into Dynamo it's great. I just do some type reflection on my Poco classes and shove them in like so:

```
     var doc = new Document();
     foreach (PropertyInfo prop in model.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
     {
         var propName = (string)prop.Name;
         // dont add if value is null
         if (prop.GetValue(model, null) != null)
         {
             if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                 doc[propName] = (string)prop.GetValue(model, null);
             if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(List<string>))
                 doc[propName] = (List<string>)prop.GetValue(model, null);
             if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(float))
                 doc[propName] = (float)prop.GetValue(model, null);
         }
     }
```

But here in the repo, I'd like to not have to write this ugly manual cast when retrieving items. **Is there a AWS helper to make this less manual?** I guess I could write the inverse of the above loop and get the attribute property names then test for null on each N, S, SS  type etc.

```
var request = new ScanRequest
            {
                TableName = TableName.User,
            };

            var response = client.Scan(request);
            var collection = (from item in response.ScanResult.Items
                from att in item
                select new User(att.Value.S, att.Value.N, att.Value.S, att.Value.N, att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.S,
                    att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.S, att.Value.SS, att.Value.SS)).ToList();

            return collection.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Object Persistence Model feature of the .NET SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html). This allows you to annotate your .NET objects with attributes that then direct the SDK how that data should be stored in DynamoDB.

Comment: The object persistence model doesn't appear to support pagination. If you need that it looks like you have to use the other models (Document or Low Level), as confirmed in this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-document-model-manual-pagination/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the built-in `FromDocument` method to convert the `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` to your class of type T

```
List<MyClass> result = new List<MyClass>();

var response = await client.QueryAsync(request);

        foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item in response.Items)
        {
            var doc = Document.FromAttributeMap(item);
            var typedDoc = context.FromDocument<MyClass>(doc);
            result.Add(typedDoc);
        }
```

Comment: What is "context" in your example? Where it comes from?

Comment: @Kamarey, context is an instance of DynamoDBContext. example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CRUDHighLevelExample1.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it the LOOOOOONG way. It was kind of fun to use type reflection to create my own casting function. Would have been more fun if it weren't at 2 AM.

The Pavel's answer is more official, but this still works like a charm.

```
public static T ResultItemToClass<T>(Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> resultItem) where T : new()
        {
            var resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            Type type = typeof(T);
            T ret = new T();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AttributeValue> p in resultItem)
                if (p.Value != null)
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in p.Value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
                        if (prop.GetValue(p.Value, null) != null)              
                            {
                                if (prop.Name == "S")
                                    type.GetProperty(p.Key).SetValue(ret, prop.GetValue(p.Value, null), null);                                    

                                if (prop.Name == "SS")
                                    type.GetProperty(p.Key).SetValue(ret, (List<string>)prop.GetValue(p.Value, null), null);

                                if (prop.Name == "N")
                                    type.GetProperty(p.Key).SetValue(ret,  Convert.ToInt32(prop.GetValue(p.Value, null)), null);

                                // TODO: add some other types. Too tired tonight
                            }                           
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: How can we set this for prop.Name == "M" ?

Answer (score 0):

From the aws Document result class, you can use the instance method: .ToJson(), then deserialise into your class.

Comment: This answer needs some work and as stated the Object persistence will do a much better job.

Answer (score 0):

Generic method convert Dynamo table to c# class as an extension function.

```
public static List<T> ToMap<T>(this List<Document> item)
    {
        List<T> model = (List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<T>));
        foreach (Document doc in item)
        {
            T m = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            var propTypes = m.GetType();
            foreach (var attribute in doc.GetAttributeNames())
            {
                var property = doc[attribute];
                if (property is Primitive)
                {
                    var properties = propTypes.GetProperty(attribute);
                    if (properties != null)
                    {
                        var value = (Primitive)property;
                        if (value.Type == DynamoDBEntryType.String)
                        {
                            properties.SetValue(m, Convert.ToString(value.AsPrimitive().Value));
                        }
                        else if (value.Type == DynamoDBEntryType.Numeric)
                        {
                            properties.SetValue(m, Convert.ToInt32(value.AsPrimitive().Value));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (property is DynamoDBBool)
                {
                    var booleanProperty = propTypes.GetProperty(attribute);
                    if (booleanProperty != null)
                        booleanProperty.SetValue(m, property.AsBoolean());
                }
            }
            model.Add(m);
        }
        return model;
    }
```